# Load custom CSS before admin CSS

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to use the jQuery Datatables plugin in my WordPress dashboard but the native WordPress admin CSS styling is overiding the datatables CSS, I am calling them like this...

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_scripts');
function admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('datatables', '//cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js', array('jquery'),'1.21', true );
    wp_enqueue_style('datatables-css', '//cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css', 99);
}
```

Is there a way to change the priority so it loads the datatables CSS first?

Comment: Try changing the action priority `add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_scripts', 30 );` 30 or more.

Answer (score 1):

By default they should already be loading after the core admin styles. I suspect the CSS isn't even being loaded because you have an invalid parameter in your `wp_enqueue_style()` call. Its parameters are the same as `wp_enqueue_script()`. Where you have `99` is where dependencies are actually defined. So WordPress is looking for `99` to be loaded, not finding it, and skipping the enqueue.

So I would re-write that as follows:

```
 wp_enqueue_style( 'datatables-css', '//cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css', 'datatables' );
```

What this does is loads the stylesheet but only if the JavaScript file is loaded.

Comment: There's no technical difference between `wp_enqueue_style( 'datatables-css', '//cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css', 'datatables' );` and `wp_enqueue_style('datatables-css', '//cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css', 99);`. Because you have to pass the depency argument as array otherwise an empty array will be assigned. Check this https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/class-wp-dependency.php#L70

Comment: @obiPlabon But what will that `99` do then since it's in the place of the dependencies parameter?

Comment: Having seen the code what do you think? `99` will be ignored mate

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that as this is all about CSS specificity. What you need to do is wrap the datatable in a unique div and then use that to specifically target the elements in your CSS.

For example (I don't know the CSS, BTW, so this is just a general example)

Wrap the table element in `<div class="myClass">`

Use the Inspector in your browser to find out exactly what line of CSS is being used for the styling you want to override.

If the CSS for an element is `table.dataTable tr.dataTr td.dataTd` then if you add the wrapper div to that it should override it as it's more specific, ie: `.myClass table.dataTable tr.dataTr td.dataTd`

You might need to experiment a bit until you get exactly the right combination to override the specificity. I usually find a wrapper element is enough, but sometimes I find adding a specific class to the (eg)table element helps (if you can), so it might be: `table.dataTable.myTableClass tr.dataTr td.dataTd`

Hope that helps